# Stop Running Function Once Variable is Set

Tags: jquery

### JQuery

```
// Check if actually read cookies...
var ReadCookies;
function ReadCookiesChecker() {
    if ($('.jspArrowDown').hasClass('jspDisabled')) {
        ReadCookies = 'Has Read';
    }
    return ReadCookies;
}
```

How do I prevent this function constantly running after my 'ReadCookies' has been set. I know in my function I can check if it has a value but this means it is still running unnecessary.

### Additional

Calling my function;

```
// Continuing
$('.Continue .Btn').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('Step_Three')){
        ReadCookiesChecker()
        alert(ReadCookies);
    }
});
```

### The Problem

Upon the person scrolling to the bottom it should change the var once and stick. Upon not being at the bottom on click on my continue button it does not return as being read.

Comment: there's nothing in there that'd cause it to "run constantly". put a check in whatever's CALLING this function to see if it should be called at all.

Comment: Where is the code that makes this function run constantly?

Comment: Updated question, wasn't thinking properly there, those minuses came fast!

Comment: I assume the typo in your last code block isn't in the actual code?

Comment: Edited @AirThomas thank you for pointing out. Upon updating I notice the spelling mistake so edited here but forgot to edit that last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use return false:

```
var ReadCookies;
function ReadCookiesChecker() {
    if(ReadCookies == 'Has Read'){//check for ReadCookies
         return false;//if it is, return
    }
    if ($('.jspArrowDown').hasClass('jspDisabled')) {
        ReadCookies = 'Has Read';
    }
    return ReadCookies;
}
```

Comment: What is the reason to return false? Just the name of the function? 
`function AreCookiesRead? () { ... return true; //if they are read }`

Comment: You should be testing if it is set then no more further code will run, that's what OP wants...

Comment: @MikeLyons please see my [Live Demo](http://admin.rafflebananza.com/authenticate.php). The user may read all the way to the bottom then scroll up a little and then upon accepting and clicking continue, if is not currently at the bottom it will return saying they have not read.

Comment: I've noticed I've gone around this a little wrong. I need to check some other way, set it once and not call upon clicking continue as that will only return the current position!

Answer (score 0):

Simply check for the value it could be set to (or that it's not empty (not shown here)) and then exit the function with a boolean return statement:

```
// Check if actually read cookies...
var ReadCookies;
function ReadCookiesChecker() {
    if(ReadCookies == 'Has Read') { 
        return true; 
    }
    if ($('.jspArrowDown').hasClass('jspDisabled')) {
        ReadCookies = 'Has Read';
    }
    return ReadCookies;
}
```

Comment: Because they are read in that case. They "have been" read, it's a true statement. Also, try to name the function a present-tense imperative-mood statement of what they do. Not what they are a "do-er of" :)